# Cannot lookup JNDI resource on redeployment

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-jms

### The problem:

A web application of mine listens to JMS messages on a queue and processes the messages. I've written a few test cases that are to be run on a CI to confirm if messages are received and processed correctly. The CI builds the code and deploys it to a server before running tests on it.

This is the configuration that the server works with.

**Spring config**

```
<!-- JMS message listener -->
<bean id="someMessageListener" class="com.whatever.MyListener" />

<!-- Cached Connection Factory -->
<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="activeMQConnectionFactory"></property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10"></property>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Spring message listener -->
<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
    connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory" acknowledge="client"
>
    <jms:listener destination="DESTINATION" ref="someMessageListener"
        method="onMessage" id="jmsSomeMessageListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

The code inside the `MyListener` class looks up a JNDI database resource to obtain a sql `Connection`. Further processing of the JMS message relies on obtaining a valid sql connection. The binding of the JNDI resource is taken care of by tomcat using a `Resource` definition in `context.xml`.

The code works fine when I run it for the first time on the CI. When I redeploy the WAR using the maven targets `tomcat:undeploy` and `tomcat:deploy`, my message listener is no longer able to obtain a database connection. I get the following exception

**Exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
Name [comp/env/jdbc/postgres] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
```

This is the code that looks up the `DataSource`

**JNDI lookup code**

```
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres");
```

### What I've tried to solve the problem:

I suspect an older context is lingering around even after the application has been undeployed due to a leak or improper undeployment. Attempting to gracefully shutdown the message listener (jmsSomeMessageListener) from a `ServletContextListener`'s `onDestroy()` using the `stop()` method did not help.

Stopping the message listener before calling `tomcat:undeploy` did not help either. I was hoping that restarting the listener would force it to use a new context.

### Question:

Why does the `Context` become stale after a redeployment ? This only happens on the listener and not on other code that looks up the same `Context`. What can I do to fix the problem ? (I'm even open to restarting the server for each CI build to punt the problem temporarily)

Comment: Today I got same issue. After redeploys sometimes Tomcat can't find JNDI resource, previously visible....Do you solve issue?

Comment: Nope. I'm restarting the server each time. Still have not gotten around to this.

Comment: Same problem. In my case I'm looking up a PoolingDataSource, and when the lookup fails I attempt to create a new connection pool. It fails because it has the same name as a pool that exited in the last context (although I can't look it up).  I'm using JBoss 7.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem where my database pool stayed open but I was unable to look it up using JNDI after a redeployment of my war.  I solved the issue by closing the connection and unbinding it from JNDI when the war is undeployed.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
public class MyClass implements ServletContextListener
{
    private String db = "foo";

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        PGPoolingDataSource connectionPool = 
                (PGPoolingDataSource)new InitialContext().lookup(db);
        if(connectionPool != null)
        {
            connectionPool.close();
            new InitialContext().unbind(db);
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add a block to your web.xml registering your class as a listener:

```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>com.foo.bar.MyClass</listener-class>
   </listener>
```